# Programmatically Show Document Name Popover for Document-Based App

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-yosemite, titlebar

We have a custom window and titlebar for a document-based app, and we would like to support the document name popover (in Yosemite) with the standard disclosure button that appears beside the document title. Here is an image of the disclosure button and the popover when it is clicked (from TextEdit):

[image: Document Name Popover]

Is there a way to programmatically show this document name popover for a custom disclosure button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the answer to this question is: you can't - without getting into private APIs.